# как рендерить статичное изображение webgl

Tags: javascript, html5, webgl

При ресайзе я вызываю две функции : `resizeCanvas` и `renderGl`
`resizeCanvas` изменяет размер `canvas`, а `renderGl` рендерит изображение
Я не понимаю, что нужно писать когда заново перерисовываешь статичное изображение

```js
function renderGl(gl) {
  // gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  // gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

нужно ли делать `gl.clearColor` и `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` и почему без них всё рендерится нормально?
И зачем их делать, мы таким образом очищаем память на видеокарте?

```js
function debounce(f, t) {
  return function(args) {
    let previousCall = this.lastCall;
    this.lastCall = Date.now();
    if (previousCall && ((this.lastCall  -  previousCall) <= t)) {
      clearTimeout(this.lastCallTimer);
    }
    this.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => f(args), t);
  }
}

function resizeCanvas(gl) {
  const realToCSSPixels = window.devicePixelRatio; // для дисплеев повышенной четкости HD-DPI
  const width = Math.floor(gl.canvas.scrollWidth * realToCSSPixels);
  const height = Math.floor(gl.canvas.scrollHeight * realToCSSPixels);
  gl.canvas.width = width;
  gl.canvas.height = height;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

function initwebgl(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext("webgl2") ||
    canvas.getContext("webgl") ||
    canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
  if (!context) {
    alert('У вас не поддерживается webgl, используйте новый Google Chrome');
  }
  return context;
}

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  const sucess = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (sucess) {
    return shader;
  }

  console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

function createProgram(gl, v, f) {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, v);
  gl.attachShader(program, f);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  const sucess = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (sucess) {
    return program;
  }

  console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

function drawWebglCanvas(f, v, gl) {
  function renderGl(gl) {
    // gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }

  function resizeGlAndCanvas(gl) {
    resizeCanvas(gl);
    const resizeFunc = () => {
      resizeCanvas(gl);
      renderGl(gl);
    };
    const lazyFunc = debounce(resizeFunc, 10);
    window.addEventListener('resize', lazyFunc);
  }
  resizeGlAndCanvas(gl);
  const vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, v);
  const fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, f);
  const program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
  const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  const positions = new Float32Array([
    0, 0,
    0, 0.5,
    0.7, 0
  ]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation); // включаем атрибут
  // Привязываем буфер положений
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Указываем атрибуту, как получать данные от positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  const size = 2; // 2 компоненты на итерацию
  const type = gl.FLOAT; // наши данные - 32-битные числа с плавающей точкой
  const normalize = false; // не нормализовать данные
  const stride = 0; // 0 = перемещаться на size * sizeof(type) каждую итерацию для получения следующего положения
  const offset = 0; // начинать с начала буфера
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  const primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
  const count = 3;
  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

const fragment = document.querySelector('#fragment').innerHTML;
const vertex = document.querySelector('#vertex').innerHTML;
const canvas = document.querySelector('#glcanvas');
const gl = initwebgl(canvas);
if (gl) {
  drawWebglCanvas(fragment, vertex, gl);
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#glcanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="glcanvas">

<script type="notjs" id="vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;
void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
}
</script>

<script type="notjs" id="fragment">
precision mediump float;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0.5, 1); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: ресайз очищает буферы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)` - определяем значения, используемые для задания цвета во время очистки буферов цвета

`gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` - очистить буфер цвета по значениям, которые мы заранее задали.

При ресайзе нам нужно просто очищать буфер цвета по тем значениям, что указали ранее, т.е. вызывать `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`